# IMA SDK HTML5 Video player controls not showing

Tags: html5-video, google-ima, imasdk

We are running sample IMA HTML5 example but player is not getting controls even controls property has been set.

Below is the link of sample -

http://adunits.popmunch.com/neema/googleads_ima_html5_samples/simple/index.html

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the controls attribute in video tag.

You can also set `video.controls=true` in your js